# How to use a static IP from google cloud as a proxy in an ssh tunnel to 3rd party

Tags: proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, static-ip

I need to setup a static IP for 3rd parties to whitelist, and I need to use that IP from my laptop to connect to that 3rd party using SFTP and / or SSH.

I'm thinking that I need to create a static IP in google cloud, and then somehow setup a proxy that use that IP outbound.

How can I possibly set that up in Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need for this is a simple `f1-micro` instance with a static IP running any UNIX-like operating system.

I had an answer all written up, but then I found [this gem](https://askubuntu.com/a/311454/755154) which seems to perfectly and correctly do exactly what you want.

Just for fun, here are the two potential approaches I was going to suggest:

- As two separate connections: you first SSH into the "proxy" instance, then SSH out from there; for convenience you can use [SSH agent forwarding](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html) (in the `Public Key Access with Agent Forwarding` section, but I recommend reading it from the beginning; it's not that long).
- One connection: You can tunnel directly using SSH; there's a [Google Cloud Platform Community Tutorial on SSH tunneling](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce) covering it.

Comment: for the second option creating a tunnel - how would I bind a static IP to that?

Comment: @gottlieb76 I recommend following the link behind the words "this gem" and using that instead. If you want to implement one of the other suggestions instead, you create the VM using a static IP; go into the Networking section of the VM details to select that.

Comment: I read through it, but it explains how to connect to a specific host (hostname or IP), however, I need to expose a static IP from the proxy, not connect to a specific host.

Comment: @gottlieb76 You can connect to any host you want from it. The intermediate machine is the VM on GCP with the static IP. It isn't only for one destination!

Comment: I made sense of everything and got it working - thanks for the help. Much appreciated. I finally settled on the last option, the create a SSH tunnel - super simple once I figured it out.